# Can we stream only the audio from a YouTube video using python without actually downloading it?

Tags: python, audio, video, youtube

Now, using the 'pafy' module and VLC extension, we can stream a youtube video with a simple program like this:

```py
import vlc
import pafy
  
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ'
 
video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest()
  
media = vlc.MediaPlayer(best.url)
  
media.play()
```

Also, we can download and extract audio from it using this simple program again:

```py
import vlc
import pafy
import moviepy.editor as mp

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ'
 
video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest()
best.download()

clip = mp.VideoFileClip('filename.mp4')
clip.audio.write_audiofile(r"result.mp3")
```

These 2 are very simple tasks. But now my main question is, can I "only" stream the audio from the video link 'WITHOUT HAVING TO DOWNLOAD' it and extract it. I looked upon the web for answers, but found almost none. So, if it is possible, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: "downland" and "stream" are the exact same thing. "stream" just means its download at the same speed it's played. Is what you are asking, "how to download the audio, and not the video?" If so, please update the question to reflect that.

Comment: until what I understand, the key difference is that a streaming file is simply played as it becomes available, while a download is stored onto memory. And I don't want to store it in memory. It's just like you're watching a YouTube video, basically, you're not downloading it, but streaming it online.

Comment: "download" means moving bits over a network. What the computer does with them once the are downloaded is not related. What do you cal it if you copy bits from a server as fast as possible then just throw them away?